# OOP, dependency injections and constructors

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, constructor

I'm trying to design some classes that requires use of an outside object. The outside object is from a third party library.
Example in psudocode

```
Class A {
    protected $foo

    public function __construct(\ThirdParty\Foo $foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo
    }
}
```

These sub classes are created to hold methods that have slightly different implementations depending on how Foo is instantiated.

```
Class AA extends A {
    $fooInfo = 'red'
    public function __construct($foo) {
        parent::__construct($foo)
    }
    public function get() {
        return $this->foo->getTypeX();
    }
}

Class AB extends A {
    $fooInfo = 'white'
    public function __construct($foo) {
        parent::__construct($foo)
    }
    public function get() {
        return $this->foo->getTypeY();
    }
}
```

But to use the third party app I need the value in $fooInfo when I instantiate it.

```
$clientRed = new Foo('red')
$clientWhite = new Foo('white')
```

So when I instantiate AA or AB how am I to get the color information to Foo object?

```
$client = new AA(new Foo(????))
```

Comment: Cant edit tags for some reason, may want to mention this is PHP though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AA extends A {
  const fooInfo = 'red'
  ...

$client = new AA(new Foo(AA::fooInfo))
```

You can also create a factory:

```
function CreateClient ($clientType) {
    return new $clientType(new Foo($clientType::fooInfo))
}

$client = CreateClient('AA')
```

Comment: [*Constants do not have a dollar sign ($) before them*](http://php.net/const) Eg: `const FOO_INFO = 'red';` you maybe meant `static` Eg: `static $fooInfo = 'red';`

Comment: @Touki: I'm not that proficient in PHP. I think constant is more appropriate here. Will remove the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

Use a factory to instantiate the objects for you.

Like so:

```
class ClientFactory {
    public function getClient($objectType){
        switch(objectType) {
           case 'AA':
              $fooInfo = 'red';
              break;
           case 'AB':
              $fooInfo = 'white';
              break;
        }
        $foo = new Foo($fooInfo);
        return new $objectType($foo);
    }
}
```

Your client now doesn't need to know anything about the `Foo` class created.  It just knows that it has one.  And if the requirements change for the classes (AB now needs a 'red' Foo also), you can change it in one location.